# Re-order boxplots by site ID

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

I have a dataset with multi-date temperature sampling from four wells that form a straight line. The dataframe is presented as such:

```
   Date           Well Site    Temperature
   11-07-2015     Two          14
   01-18-2016     Two          7
   11-07-2015     Four         16
   01-18-2016     Four         10
   11-07-2015     Six          16
   01-18-2016     Six          9
   11-07-2015     Eight        15
   01-18-2016     Eight        8
```

As you can see the data frame has the wells ordered by their site but when I use ggplot and geom_boxplot they are ordered alphabetically. What I want to create is a geom_boxplot that shows the wells in the following order -(Left) Eight - Six - Four - Two (Right) because that is how the wells are positioned at the site from East to West.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lot of ways to do this. Here's a way using `scale_x_discrete`:

```
ggplot(d, aes(`Well Site`, Temperature))+
    geom_boxplot()+
    scale_x_discrete(limits = c("Eight", "Six", "Four", "Two"))
```

You could also make `Well Site` a factor:

```
d$`Well Site` <- factor(d$`Well Site`, levels = c("Eight", "Six", "Four", "Two"))
```